# php check whether user has checked in or not

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to write a PHP server side to check whether the user has checked in or note. The PHP file will query a MySQL databases to see whether the `userID` has date checked in. If not the PHP file will insert a date according to `userID`. If there is already a record for that date, it will prompt message "already checked in". I wrote the following code but it can not detect whether the record exists (it always inserts a new record). What is the wrong part?

```
<?php



if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $staffID = $_POST['staffID'];
 $date = $_POST['localDate'];

 require_once('dbconnect.php');


 $sqlcheck = "SELECT Date FROM StaffAttendacne WHERE StaffID = '$staffID' AND Date ='$date'";

 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sqlcheck);


 if ((mysqli_num_rows($res)) > 0){
 echo "You have already checked in";
 }else {
     echo "Perform Check in $date";
     $sql = "INSERT INTO StaffAttendance (StaffID, Date) VALUES ('$staffID','$date')";
     mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: what is the format of $date and Date in the database ?  it's possible that the date doesn't match exactly, like, for example, if the database Date has a time stamp and $date does not.  Also, please be aware that your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I convert date to string format and use date from my android app to push to server

Comment: please give an example value for $date and the corresponding value in the database that you're attempting to compare to.

Comment: Date in table is varchar format. ex: 2015-11-09 (value will be taken from my app. my app use local date which will be converted into string format also

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh Your table date column datatype is varchar.. Why??

Comment: because i push data type string from my android app to the php file. dont know is that the correct way

Comment: so $date would also be '2015-11-09' without a timestamp ?

Comment: i tried $date as string but still inserted everytime. I just want check if record existed before inserted current datetime. is there an effective way to do that task?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for today date you can try using CURDATE() function

```
$sqlcheck = "SELECT Date FROM StaffAttendacne WHERE StaffID = '$staffID' AND Date = CURDATE() ";
```

Comment: Thanks for yrs respond. Can u explain further. I want to check whether the record for that date has already been inserted to the database

Comment: So mean that we ll change the SQL query? Can give example for the query should be?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh SELECT Date FROM StaffAttendacne WHERE StaffID = 'whatever your id is' AND Date = '2015-11-10'

Comment: thanks a lot. and what data type should Date in database should be (varchar, date, datetime, timestamp)?

Comment: I try modify the code and changed data type of Date into date. but it still insert evertime

Comment: <?php
 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 $staffID = $_POST['staffID'];
 $date = $_POST['localDate'];
  
 require_once('dbconnect.php');
 
 
 $sqlcheck = "SELECT Date FROM StaffAttendacne WHERE StaffID = '$staffID' AND Date = CURDATE()";
 
 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sqlcheck);
   
 
 if ((mysqli_num_rows($res)) > 0){
 echo "You have already checked in";
 }else {
     echo "Perform Check in $date";
     $sql = "INSERT INTO StaffAttendance (StaffID, Date) VALUES ('$staffID',CURDATE())";
     mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 }
 }
 mysqli_close($con);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe date format is not same between posting data and database table. You can use date_format sql function. Its may help. Example below. Thanks.

$sqlcheck = "SELECT Date FROM StaffAttendacne WHERE StaffID = '$staffID' AND DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT('$date','%Y-%m-%d')";

Comment: thanks but when change to your sql. it still insert everytime. What data type SQL should be in?

Comment: you can use date or datetime. its up to u.sql generally store date in 'Y-m-d' format. thanks.

Comment: changed to date or datetime still not working. may be can just used the server date to check with the database. no need to push date from app?

Comment: You can push date from app but you need to format it like mysql date format. Please check your inserted date. What is the format? What is your table date datatype? Thanks.

Comment: I tried used this simple declare $date = date("Y-m-d"); and datatype in SQL is date but still not work, may be the if function not correct?

Comment: thanks i've just made it work by using $date = date("Y-m-d"); but 1 more prob is the time inserted into MySQL database is 2 hour earlier than the time app run. my be something with the timezone. can we set timezone to be inserted into MySQL?

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh You can set the default time zone by using php function date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");

Comment: Thanks. Mine is Singapore. Shuould be  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singaporeok"); do wee need "ok" at the end?